# How to split pipe-separated (|) values of a single column of data table into multiple columns

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datatable `dtRecords`. It contains a column `Token`, which contains pipe- (|) separated values

e.g.

```
234|82|91
235|81|90
237|83|95
238|85|98
```

I want the output in another table say `dtCompleteRecords` with 3 columns `a, b, c` having corresponding values of the `Token` column of `dtRecords`.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: use string.split("|")
that will sort out your problem

Comment: Does your string contains linebreaks ? "after the edit"

Comment: have you tried anything yet???

Comment: Is there any reason not to create three new columns in your original dataset and split this data out into them rather than using a different table?

Comment: @chris:I was reading a record from some data source , which gives me in the aforementioned format . i.e , pipe separated rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
 var dtCompleteRecords = new DataTable("CompleteRecords");
 dtCompleteRecords.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("a", typeof(string)));
 dtCompleteRecords.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("b", typeof(string)));
 dtCompleteRecords.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("c", typeof(string)));


dtRecords.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row["Token"].ToString().Split('|'))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(array => dtCompleteRecords.Rows.Add(array));
```

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you have string:

```
string str = "234|82|91 235|81|90 237|83|95 238|85|98"
```

Use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to get an array of string element.

```
string[] strArray = str.Split('|');
```

Later you can insert these values in the datatable.

Comment: Just for your reference the original question had the data on four separate lines but not correctly marked up as code. I edited it to display as I think the OP intended. not sure if you want to edit your answer correspondingly (though the essence of your answer remains unchanged).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `Split('|')` method, that is applied to string. So e.g. `myCell.Text.Split('|')`

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
        DataTable dt = yourdatatable;
        DataTable dtable2 = new DataTable();
        dtable2.Columns.Add("column1", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtable2.Columns.Add("column2", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtable2.Columns.Add("column3", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        string value = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            value = dt.Rows[0][i].ToString();
            string[] splitPipeValue = value.Split('|');
            DataRow drow = dtable2.NewRow();
            drow[0] = splitPipeValue[0].ToString();
            drow[1] = splitPipeValue[1].ToString();
            drow[2] = splitPipeValue[2].ToString();
            dtable2.Rows.Add(drow);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's working too..but it's taking too much tim for my liking as I have some 1 million records in my database.Though , thanks for your help.